# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException when setting a new int number to a specific position of an ArrayList

Tags: java, string, exception, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

A class `AnyCorrectChoiceQuestion` is intended to create questions that allow multiple correct choices. The respondent should provide any one of the correct choices. The answer string should contain all of the correct choices, separated by spaces.

There is also a question demo to test this class.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
  A question with multiple choices.
 */

public class AnyCorrectChoiceQuestion extends Question
{
   private ArrayList<String> choices;
   private ArrayList<Integer> correctChoices;
   private int counter = 0;
   private int answerNum = 0;

   /**
     Constructs a choice question with no choices.
    */

   public AnyCorrectChoiceQuestion()
   {
      choices = new ArrayList<String>();
      correctChoices = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   }

   /**
     Adds an answer choice to this question.
     @param choice the choice to add
     @param correct true if this is the correct choice, false otherwise
   */

   public void addChoice(String choice, boolean correct)
   {
      choices.add(choice);
      answerNum++;
      if(correct) 
      {
         correctChoices.set(counter, answerNum);
         counter++;
      }
   }

   public void display()
   {
      // Display the question text
      super.display();
      // Display the answer choices
      for (int i = 0; i < choices.size(); i++)
      {
         int choiceNumber = i + 1;
         System.out.println(choiceNumber + ": " + choices.get(i));     
      }
   }


   // check the index between the response and our original answers, only one correspondence is needed.

   public boolean checkAnswer(int response)
   {
      for(int i = 0; i <= correctChoices.size() - 1; i++)
      {
         if(response == correctChoices.get(i))
         {
            return true;
         }
      }

      return false;
   }
}
```

Here is the tester:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
  This program shows a simple quiz with two choice questions.
 */

public class QuestionDemo2
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      AnyCorrectChoiceQuestion first = new AnyCorrectChoiceQuestion();
      first.setText("What was the original name of the Java language?");
      first.addChoice("*7", false);
      first.addChoice("Duke", true);
      first.addChoice("Oak", true);
      first.addChoice("Gosling", true);

      AnyCorrectChoiceQuestion second = new AnyCorrectChoiceQuestion();
      second.setText("In which country was the inventor of Java born?");
      second.addChoice("Australia", true);
      second.addChoice("Canada", true);
      second.addChoice("Denmark", false);
      second.addChoice("United States", false);

      presentQuestion(first);
      presentQuestion(second);
   }

   /**
     Presents a question to the user and checks the response.
     @param q the question
   */

   public static void presentQuestion(AnyCorrectChoiceQuestion q)
   {
      q.display();
      System.out.print("Your answer: ");
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      String response = in.nextLine();
      System.out.println(q.checkAnswer(response));
   }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you provide the full stacktrace?

Comment: `list.set(position, element)` allows you to *replace* already existing element at specified position in list with different one, but to make that possible list needs to first contain element at such position. So you first need to *add* that element to list.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is

```
correctChoices.set(counter, answerNum);
```

Just use `correctChoices.add(answerNum)`

The ArrayList is initialized with the size 0. So you can't set an element. And the set method replaces a value. There is no value in the list at any position, so the method returns the exception.

```
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList();
    System.out.println(list.size()); // size = 0
```

Comment: This will append to list instead of replacing it.

Comment: But the list is empty in the beginning, so there is nothing to replace!